# Creating a web service to connect with my chatbot

Tags: chatbot

I was going through the tutorial at https://api.ai/slack/ to create a chatbot and I'm not sure what a web hook and web service is. I know simple java programming and created test classes in a netbeans project to simulate the input from the chatbot.

How do I connect my locally-hosted application to api.ai through a web hook to create a slack chatbot?

Answer (score 0):

Webhook is a HTTP callback URL that you are suppose to provide api.ai. It is a connector between api.ai and web service. Now when slack sends a message to api.ai, it would send an event notification to your web application service.
To generate a temporary callback URL you could use the following link : https://ngrok.com/
Steps :  1) If you do not have a callback URL, follow the steps in the ngrok website for installation
2) Run your application on port 8080
3) Now execute the ngrok.exe file from command prompt with the following command [ngrok.exe http 8080].  This would give you the webhook URL which you could give api.ai